# lie awake or stay awake?

Tags: meaning, language-evolution

Soon, we will lie awake to talking and laughing until the sunrise

Soon, we will stay awake for talking and laughing until sunrise

Comment: Soon we will be staying awake all night, talking and laughing until sunrise.

Comment: See definition of "lie". The one that means not standing or sitting, but in horizontal position. To "lie awake" implies being in bed.

Answer (score 2):

"Lie awake" has the connotation of attempting to sleep, but failing.

"Stay awake" implies that being awake is the plan.

However, if your goal is to communicate a great time, I would use something like this:

*Soon, we will **stay up all night**, talking and laughing until dawn*

This has the connotation, at least in U.S. English, of a fun time. Stay awake is close in strict meaning, but the cultural implications are less fun. It's not *wrong*, per se, just not as strong.

Comment: See definition of "lie". The one that means not standing or sitting, but in horizontal position. To "lie awake" implies being in bed.